# Double Pendulum returning nan results. Why?

Tags: c++, math, double, sfml, pendulum

When I run this code the double pendulum shows for a split second and then disappears. It seems most of the variables in the formula, num1, num2, etc., start returning nan after that split second when the pendulum disappears. Can anyone see why? I thought it had to do with converting degrees to radians at 180 degrees so I added the if statement in my convert function.

Here is the link to the Double Pendulum motion formula. I broke down the formula into pieces for simplicity's sake. https://www.myphysicslab.com/pendulum/double-pendulum-en.html

This idea came from Coding Train's Double Pendulum video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uWzPe_S-RVE

```
#undef __STRICT_ANSI__
#include "window.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

namespace Window
{
    sf::ContextSettings settings;

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 600), "Window", sf::Style::Close | sf::Style::Titlebar, settings);

    void init()
    {
        settings.depthBits = 24;
        settings.majorVersion = 4;
        settings.minorVersion = 6;  //OpenGL 4.6

        glewInit();
        glViewport(0,0, 600, 600);
    }

    void close()
    {
        window.close();
    }

    void update()
    {
        window.display();
    }

    void checkForClose()
    {
        sf::Event windowEvent;
        while (window.pollEvent(windowEvent))
        {
            if (windowEvent.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                close();
            }
        }
    }

    bool isOpen()
    {
        return window.isOpen();
    }

    double convDeg(double deg)
    {
        if (deg == 180.0)
        {
            return 0.0;
        }

        else
        {
            return deg * M_PI / 180.0;
        }
    }

    void runLoop()
    {
        double r1 = 100;
        double m1 = 40;
        double a1 = 90;
        double a1_v = 0;

        double r2 = 100;
        double m2 = 40;
        double a2 = 30;
        double a2_v = 0;

        double x1 = 0;
        double x2 = 0;
        double y1 = 0;
        double y2 = 0;

        double g = 0.005;

        double num1 = 0;
        double num2 = 0;
        double num3 = 0;
        double num4 = 0;
        double den = 0;

        double a1_a = 0;
        double a2_a = 0;

        while (window.isOpen())
        {
            num1 = -g * (2 * m1 + m2) * std::sin(convDeg(a1));
            num2 = -m2 * g * std::sin(convDeg(a1-2*a2));
            num3 = -2*std::sin(convDeg(a1-a2))*m2;
            num4 = a2_v*a2_v*r2+a1_v*a1_v*r1*std::cos(convDeg(a1-a2));
            den = r1 * (2*m1+m2-m2*cos(convDeg(2*a1-2*a2)));
            a1_a = (num1 + num2 + num3*num4) / den;

            num1 = 2 * std::sin(convDeg(a1-a2));
            num2 = (a1_v*a1_v*r1*(m1+m2));
            num3 = g * (m1 + m2) * std::cos(convDeg(a1));
            num4 = a2_v*a2_v*r2*m2*std::cos(convDeg(a1-a2));
            den = r2 * (2*m1+m2-m2*std::cos(convDeg(2*a1-2*a2)));
            a2_a = (num1*(num2+num3+num4)) / den;

            x1 = 300 + (r1 * std::sin((convDeg(a1))));
            y1 = 300 + (r1 * std::cos((convDeg(a1))));
            x2 = x1 + (r2 * std::sin((convDeg(a2))));
            y2 = y1 + (r2 * std::cos((convDeg(a2))));

            a1_v += a1_a;
            a2_v += a2_a;
            a1 += a1_v;
            a2 += a2_v;

            sf::Vertex pOne[] =
            {
                sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(300,300)),
                sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(x1,y1)),
            };

            sf::Vertex pTwo[] =
            {
                sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(x1,y1)),
                sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(x2,y2)),
            };

            window.clear();
            window.draw(pOne, 2, sf::Lines);
            window.draw(pTwo, 2, sf::Lines);

            update();
            checkForClose();

            std::cout << std::sin(convDeg(a1)) << "\n";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: and _what_ is returning `nan`? Please be precise in what you ask.

Comment: Edited for clarification.

Comment: Tip: you can enable floating point exceptions to pin down the exact point where a nan is generated.

Answer (score 0):

List of problems:

- `convDeg`: 180 and 0 degrees are not equivalent.
- Angular variables: acceleration / velocity `a1_a, a1_v` etc are in *radians*, whereas your angle variables `a1, a2` etc are in *degrees*. Every time the loop runs, your code wrongly converts degrees into radians. Do the conversion *before* the main loop.
- (Speculation based on a previous answer - I could be wrong) The formulas on MyPhysicsLab seem to contradict those from other sources, e.g. [here](http://www.physicsandbox.com/projects/double-pendulum.html) and [here](http://rotations.berkeley.edu/the-double-pendulum/); a quick calculation using Lagrangian mechanics agrees with these two sources and *not* MPL.

Comment: Where are 180 and 0 being equivalent? I have it returning 0 radians for 180 degrees.

Comment: @Don why is 0 radians equivalent to 180 degrees? Did you mean 360?

Comment: I guess I'm just really confused. When converting 180 degrees to radians and asking for the sin, it is returning a really really small number instead of just 0. That was my goal with my if statement. I assume I'm doing it wrong. Haha

Comment: @Don quick tip - you can use `fmod` to "normalize" the angle to [0, 360) degrees or [0, 2pi) radians. I gather that's (the gist of) what you were trying to implement with the if statement in `convDeg`.

Comment: I apologize. I'm new to C++. How would I do that?

Comment: @Don something like `fmod(deg, 360.0) * (M_PI / 180.0)`.

Comment: @Don the equations themselves are in radians because that is the natural unit of angle; you should convert your input angles `a1, a2` etc into radians *before* running the rest of the code.

Comment: Alright. I'll try that. Just confused why it worked for the guy in the youtube video but not for me?

Comment: @Don skip to [8:42](https://youtu.be/uWzPe_S-RVE?t=522) in that video - his input angles `a1, a2` were **already** in radians.

Comment: Wow. Didn't notice. So I made some changes and it looks closer to the expected result. Should I edit my original post with my new code?

Comment: @Don yes but don't overwrite the original incorrect code; create a new subsection